# Adding multiple columns to a dataframe with purrr and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a dataset with dates e.g.

```
id <- 1:1000
admission_date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2018/12/31'), by="day"), 1000)
discharge_date <- admission_date + days(100)

extract <- tibble(id, admission_date, discharge_date)
```

I need to attribute the number of days to relevant quarters. I have some code which can do this;

```
min_date <- min(extract$admission_date)
max_date <- max(extract$discharge_date)


for (year in year(min_date):year(max_date)) {
  for (quarter in 1:4) {
    min_start_date <- yq(paste(year, quarter)) - days(1)
    max_end_date <- yq(paste(year, quarter)) + months(3) - days(1)

    extract <-
      extract %>% mutate(
        !!paste(year, quarter) := case_when(
          # doa before start of period and dod after end of month (or missing dod) - end of month minus start of month
          (
            admission_date < min_start_date &
              discharge_date > max_end_date
          ) ~ time_length(min_start_date %--% max_end_date, "days"),
          # doa equal or greater to start of period (but within month) and dod after end of month (or missing dod)  - end of month minus doa
          (
            admission_date >= min_start_date &
              admission_date <= max_end_date &
              discharge_date > max_end_date
          ) ~ time_length(admission_date %--% max_end_date, "days"),
          # doa on or before start of period and dod on or before end of month (but within month)  - dod minus start of month
          (
            admission_date <= min_start_date &
              discharge_date <= max_end_date &
              discharge_date > min_start_date
          ) ~ time_length(min_start_date %--% discharge_date, "days"),
          # remainder - doa after start of period and dod on or before end of period  - dod minus doa
          (
            admission_date > min_start_date &
              discharge_date <= max_end_date
          ) ~ time_length(admission_date %--% discharge_date, "days"),
          TRUE ~ 0
        )
      )
  }
}
```

However it's quite slow (my actual data has 2 million+ rows) and I feel this could be improved by packaging into a fuction and then using purrr (or probably furrr).

This is what I haev so far, it just seems to hang, so I'm not even sure what the issue is...

```
test <- function(data, year, quarter) {
  min_start_date <- yq(paste(year, quarter)) - days(1)
  max_end_date <- yq(paste(year, quarter)) + months(3) - days(1)

  data <-
    data %>% transmute(
      !!paste(year, quarter) := case_when(
        # doa before start of period and dod after end of month (or missing dod) - end of month minus start of month
        (
          admission_date < min_start_date &
            discharge_date > max_end_date
        ) ~ time_length(min_start_date %--% max_end_date, "days"),
        # doa equal or greater to start of period (but within month) and dod after end of month (or missing dod)  - end of month minus doa
        (
          admission_date >= min_start_date &
            admission_date <= max_end_date &
            discharge_date > max_end_date
        ) ~ time_length(admission_date %--% max_end_date, "days"),
        # doa on or before start of period and dod on or before end of month (but within month)  - dod minus start of month
        (
          admission_date <= min_start_date &
            discharge_date <= max_end_date &
            discharge_date > min_start_date
        ) ~ time_length(min_start_date %--% discharge_date, "days"),
        # remainder - doa after start of period and dod on or before end of period  - dod minus doa
        (
          admission_date > min_start_date &
            discharge_date <= max_end_date
        ) ~ time_length(admission_date %--% discharge_date, "days"),
        TRUE ~ 0
      )
    )
  return(data)
}


years = as.list(rep(year(min_date):year(max_date), 4))
quarters = as.list(rep(1:4, length(years) / 4))

library(purrr)

extract2 <- extract %>% pmap(years, quarters, test)
```

Answer (score 1):

start by creating the input list of parameters to the custom function

```
years = as.list(rep(year(min_date):year(max_date), 4))
quarters = as.list(rep(1:4, length(years) / 4))

param <- purrr::cross2(years, quarters)
```

Then create a custom function that takes the parameter list and data as input

```
test <- function(param, data) {
  year    <- param[[1]]
  quarter <- param[[2]]

  min_start_date <- yq(paste(year, quarter)) - days(1)
  max_end_date <- yq(paste(year, quarter)) + months(3) - days(1)

  data <-
    data %>% transmute(
      !!paste(year, quarter) := case_when(
        # doa before start of period and dod after end of month (or missing dod) - end of month minus start of month
        (
          admission_date < min_start_date &
            discharge_date > max_end_date
        ) ~ time_length(min_start_date %--% max_end_date, "days"),
        # doa equal or greater to start of period (but within month) and dod after end of month (or missing dod)  -     end of month minus doa
        (
          admission_date >= min_start_date &
            admission_date <= max_end_date &
            discharge_date > max_end_date
        ) ~ time_length(admission_date %--% max_end_date, "days"),
        # doa on or before start of period and dod on or before end of month (but within month)  - dod minus start of     month
        (
          admission_date <= min_start_date &
            discharge_date <= max_end_date &
            discharge_date > min_start_date
        ) ~ time_length(min_start_date %--% discharge_date, "days"),
        # remainder - doa after start of period and dod on or before end of period  - dod minus doa
        (
          admission_date > min_start_date &
            discharge_date <= max_end_date
        ) ~ time_length(admission_date %--% discharge_date, "days"),
        TRUE ~ 0
      )
    )
  data
}
```

then run the whole thing using `purrr`or `furrr`

```
library(purrr)  

extract2 <- purrr::map_dfc(param, test, extract)


library(furrr)
plan(multicore(workers = 8))

extract3 <- furrr::future_map_dfc(param, test, extract)
```